# Effect of the Tikhonov regularization on the Least Squares solution.

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

Consider the system $Ax = b$, where $b \notin \mathcal{R}(A)$. Then we look to find a least squares solution to this problem via 
$$ x_{LS} =A^{\dagger}b $$
where $A^{\dagger} = V \Sigma^{\dagger}U^*$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse with $A = U\Sigma V^*$ is the SVD of $A$. Now due to numerical considerations we may want to swap to the system 
$$\begin{pmatrix} A \\ \tau I \end{pmatrix} x =\begin{pmatrix} b\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$
This is called Tikhonov regularization. Now, the wikipedia article on this says that the least squares solution to this new system is given by
$$ \tilde{x}_{LS} = VDU^*b$$
where $D$ is the diagonal matrix with elements $\frac{\sigma_i}{\sigma_i^2 + |\tau| ^2}$. I tried to recreate this result in the following way:

In the original SVD of $A$ we have that the singular values are the positive roots of the eigenvalues of $A^*A$, i.e., $A^*Av_i = \sigma_i^2 v_i$. Now
$$\begin{pmatrix} A^* & \bar{\tau} I \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} A \\ \tau I\end{pmatrix} v_i = (A^*A + |\tau |^2) v_i = (\sigma_i^2 + |\tau|^2) v_i. $$
Shouldn't the singular values of $\begin{pmatrix} A \\ \tau I \end{pmatrix}$ be $ \sqrt{\sigma^2 + |\tau|^2}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $A = U\Sigma V^*$ is the thin SVD of $A$. Then you are correct that the singular values of the regularized matrix are the diagonal elements of the matrix $S = \sqrt{\Sigma^2 + |\tau|^2 I}$. It follows that

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
A\\
\tau I
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
U\Sigma S^{-1}\\
\tau V S^{-1}\\
\end{array}
\right]
SV^*
$$

is the thin SVD of the regularized matrix. Solving the regularized least squares problem the solution is given by

$$
\bar{x}_{LS} = VS^{-1}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
S^{-1}\Sigma U^* & \bar{\tau}S^{-1}V^*\\
\end{array}\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
b\\
0\\
\end{array}
\right]
= VS^{-2}\Sigma U^*b
= VDU^*b,
$$

where $D = S^{-2}\Sigma$. By the definition of $S$, $D$ is a diagonal matrix with elements $d_{ii} = \sigma_i/(\sigma_i^2 + |\tau|^2)$.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer!